# Framework7 resizable sheet modal

Tags: javascript, cordova, html-framework-7

I created an app with [Framework7](https://framework7.io/) and [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/). Inside the app, there's a page with a map. When I click on the map, a [sheet modal](http://framework7.io/docs/sheet-modal.html#examples) opens with form elements inside. Now, the sheet modal is just half the height of the screen. I know how to change the height of the sheet modal manually, but what I want to do is something like this (seen on [maps.me](https://maps.me/) App):

[image: maps.me slide up]

When I click on the map, the modal should open with a small height. Then it should be possible to resize the modal by dragging it up like seen on the gif.

By now I didn't found a way to do this. Anyone ideas/hints how to get this done? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Framework7 v4, there is now a Sheet Modal with the option [Swipe Step](https://framework7.io/docs/sheet-modal.html#swipe-step). Seems like the best solution to me :-)